# Keybinding tooltip on action disappears after changing in with method setToolTip()

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, tooltip, jface

I have an action defined in my java class and keybinding and binding to it in plugins.xml file. When I first start my application, I see my keybinding in tooltip (that's how it's suppose to be) but after changing tooltip with setToolTip(String toolTip), button binding disappears from the toolbar action button,but keybinding still works. How do I show it again, or how do I get specific keybinding for my action, because getAccelerator() method returns 0.
This is my code for action class

```
public class SampleAction extends DiagramAction{


public static final String ID = "sampleFunction";
 private void initData() {
        setId(ID);
        setText(Messages.cmd_AddBranchAction_text);
        setToolTipText(Messages.cmd_AddBranchAction_desc);
    }
    @Override
      public void refresh() {
         super.refresh();
       //checks if button in toolbar is enabled
          boolean isEnabled = isEnabled();
        if(isEnabled) {
            setToolTipText("Do something");
        } else {
            setToolTipText("Node not selected, select a node");
         }
     }
  }
```

This is how it is defined in plugin.xml

```
 <key
        commandId="com.sample.sampleFunction"
        contextId="org.eclipse.ui.context.window"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
        sequence="M1+A" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `IBindingService` to get the text for the key binding for a command:

```
TriggerSequence activeBinding = bindingService.getBestActiveBindingFor("command id");
if (activeBinding != null && !activeBinding.isEmpty()) {
    String acceleratorText = activeBinding.format();
}
```

In a view or editor this will get the binding service:

```
IBindingService service = (IBindingService)getSite().getService(IBindingService.class);
```

elsewhere you can use

```
IBindingService bindingSvc = (IBindingService)PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getAdapter(IBindingService.class);
```

Comment: This is actually works. But what is the cause of the behavior? That is just seems strange. Did i do something wrong or is this a bug in eclipse?

Comment: The tool tip showing the key binding is just the default tool tip. If you set a specific tool tip you are replacing that default.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured out myself. But default tooltip behavior is strange, because action inits with my desired tooltip and with added key. Is there anyway to know if accelerator tooltip already added? Because getToolTip() method just gives you tooltip without accelerator binding.

Comment: Not sure, this looks to be platform specific as I don't get this at all on my Mac.

Comment: Ok, thanks again. Last question. Well, is there anyway to disable default tooltiping for certain actions?